# tkinter deforms my frames after inserting objects

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

So I want to insert some objects in a frame, but when I firstly added a button the frames where were they weren't suppoused to.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZwwi.png)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNS2t.png)

And this is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1200x700")

# Main frames
frame1 = tk.Frame(root, width=1200, height=625)
frame2 = tk.Frame(root, width=1200, bg="black", height=75)

frame1.grid(row=1, column=1)
frame2.grid(row=2, column=1)

# Secondary frames
frame1browser = tk.Frame(frame1, height=625, width=850, bg="grey")
frame1a = tk.Frame(frame1,height=625, width=(1200-850))

frame1browser.grid(row=1, column=1)
frame1a.grid(row=1, column=2)

# Last frames
frame1aa = tk.Frame(frame1a, width=(1200-850),height=525, bg="green")
frame1ab = tk.Frame(frame1a, width=(1200-850),height=100, bg="yellow")

frame1aa.grid(row=1, column=1)
frame1ab.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="nswe")

# Elements that are not frames
Button1 = tk.Button(frame1ab, text="ur mother")
Button1.grid(column=1, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi David! What exactly do you want to happen? I don't fully understand what result you are trying to achieve...

Comment: Call `frame1ab.grid_propagate(0)` if you don't want the added widget to resize the frame.

Comment: @Lunar I just want to center my button inside my yellow frame for the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame ignores the width/height explicitly given if there is a widget inside it, by default. AFAIK, It finds and uses the minimum size required to fit all the widgets, also accommodating to extra properties like `sticky`, `expand` and so on.

To override this behavior, you will have to use the `<grid/pack>_propagate(False)` depending on whether you use `pack` or `grid` on the items inside the frame. Now the frame will grow/shrink as much as the size you specify.

```
frame1ab.grid_propagate(False)
```